# How can I rent a car in Caen, France with a driver's license that has been valid for less than one year?

Tags: france, car-rentals, driving-licenses, age-limits

I would like to rent a car in Caen, France but my driving license has been valid for less than one year. This is my first license - I have never been suspended from driving. I have checked most rental car companies but all require having a valid driving license for more than one year.

Are there any car rental companies without this restriction?

Comment: It is my first license.

Comment: Here is an option :
http://www.ada.fr/jeunes/index.html (they seem to have an office in Caen)

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but unfortunately agency rents the car just for people under 25 years. My age is 30.

Comment: @tommino I'd try emailing them anyway

Comment: You should call them or email them to ask. Every company has a different policy. Generally it's difficult to rent a car with less than one year of driving. That being said, they generally trust >25yo people. I don't know if your license has been valid for less than a year or if you've been driving for a longer time. If it's the latter and you can somehow prove it, you might be able to rent a car.

Comment: I have contacted almost all car rental companies, but each company requires at least 1 year valid driving licesne.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in 2017, ADA does rent cars to drivers whose license is less than one year old.

As of january 2020, I couldn't find any mention of a maximum age of 25, neither on the information page (https://www.ada.fr/offre/location-jeune-conducteur.html) nor on the terms and conditions page (https://www.ada.fr/conditions/location.html).

They do have an office in Caen (https://www.ada.fr/location-voiture-caen.html).

(I have no affiliation with ADA and actually never used that service).

Answer (score -1):

Best option in France is usually to go through collaborative renting platforms. 
The two mainstream ones are : 
 - Drivy
 - Oui Car
However ... even them ask you a minimum of 2 years permit : https://www.drivy.com/help/articles/ffffc5ffb4bf and 
https://www.ouicar.fr/info/conditions

So your best solution would be to find someone willing to take the risk through Leboncoin or ask people around.

Comment: So it's not a solution at all to the problem at hand, in what sense could it be "the best option"?